# How do programming languages implement daylight savings?

Tags: time

Programming languages of course offer timezone support, that I at least take for granted. But as the European Union is moving away from daylight savings, it struck me that I don't actually know how all this works under the hood.

Let's say starting 2022, many countries switch away from daylight savings. How do old programs react to this? And how is the language patched? Probably easy to answer once you know how it actually works.

This is not so much a practical problem for me, but asking out of interest. Tried to find an answer, but to my surprise there seems to be very little info available.

Comment: This question will be hard to answer for all existing programming languages. Please consider to rewrite your question to one specific language only. The more specific the question is, the more valuable the answers will be.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it hard coded.  Then when the rules change, all that software needs to be upgraded.  I have seen folks/software simply punt by use UTC everywhere.  I have also seen people use the well known "tz" database (aka "tzdata", "zoneinfo", "IANA timezones",the "Olson database", etc.).

Comment: An example of "all that software needs to be upgraded" (back in 2007) : https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-time-protocol-ntp/81675-dst-recommendations.html

Comment: (the smartly run networks were using UTC so they saved all that work, as well as all the work/errors converting timezones while troubleshooting!)